# I can't get Jupyterlab to make plots interactable with widgets

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have some plots that I want to interact with through widgets in Jupyterlab. 
I installed the Widgets extension like described in this [manual](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension).

Anaconda shows me that `ipywidgets` and `widgetsnbextension` are installed in my environment.

In order to get the hang of the procedure, I followed a tutorial. When executing the code, I get the error message

> 'Javascript Error: IPython is not defined'.

I tried to change the magic command to %matplotlib inline, this builds an empty plot, that doesn't show any curve.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib nbagg

x=np.linspace(0,2,1000)
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,4))
plt.suptitle('Sine Wave')

def update_plot(amp, phase, freq):
    '''
    this function linked to the sliders and 
    it replots the sine waves when the sliders are changed
    '''
    ax.clear()
    y = amp * np.sin(freq * 2 * np.pi * x + phase * 2 * np.pi)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()


amp=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max=10,value=4,description='Amp')
phase=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0,max=5,value=0,description='Phase')
freq=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1,description='Freq')

widgets.interactive(update_plot, amp=amp, phase=phase, freq=freq)
```

This should deliver a plot of a sine curve, that is interactable via the sliders to change amplitue, phase and frequency.

I don't know what I could try to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update:
I don't know what's wrong with the code I tried before, but I found another example that works and is more minimalistic as well:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

def plot_func(freq):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,1000)
    y = np.sin(x * freq)
    plt.plot(x, y)

interact(plot_func, freq = widgets.FloatSlider(value=2.5, min=1, 
max=5.0,step=0.5))
```

I'll now just use this example as template to make my own codes.